# How to get GD Image to correctly display image after adding text

Tags: php

When I add text to an image with GD Image it seems like it fails to load the rest of the image. This varies with the text string. Not adding text at all, the image appears as expected. The area to the bottom left of the image is white/background, but **not** transparent.

This is what I'm using to add the text. It's part of a larger project where images are accessed by ID from a database, which contains the filename information then loaded. $Image['fullpath'] is valid and $ErrorMsg is set elsewhere in code (correctly).

```
    $ImgString = file_get_contents($Image['fullpath']);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($ImgString);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $font = "../assets/Noteworthy-Lt.woff";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 5, 20, $color, $font, $ErrorMsg);
    imagegif($image);
```

But this renders just fine, if I don't add text.

```
    $ImgString = file_get_contents($Image['fullpath']);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($ImgString);
    imagegif($image);
```

[image: For clarity, here's an image showing what's happening]

Comment: Maybe interesting: [Add Text To Image In PHP (Using GD Library)](https://wtmatter.com/add-text-to-image-php/). Maybe about the information  sent to the browser? Have you tried saving the image and looking at it in a viewer?

Comment: I tired this and it is showing a dark blue solid fill in place of where the white is in the version sent to the browser. It seems like it's not sending all the data, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered my own answer.

It was not "seeing" all the image data because I specified the image size in the header, prior to making changes and writing the text... and therefore changing the size. Once it had that size it stopped looking at the data because it wasn't expecting any data after that.